# Accessing Azure function app proxy URL returns 403

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, http-status-code-403

I have recently setup an Azure function app with 2 proxies enabled. When I try accessing them I get 403 access forbidden error. I have setup Authentication/ Authorization by setting Authentication Providers to Azure AD. Any pointers to the cause of the 403 errors would be great.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you have setup Authentication/Authorization, so I guess you know how to request function url which was protected by AD. And I test with some situations, most of situations it can just show 401 error. The 403 error means the access token is correct but it doesn't contain required permission.

If you just have one registered in Azure AD which generated automatically when you enable "Authentication/Authorization" of your function app. You do not need to add any permissions manually, so I don't think it will show 403 error in this situation.

If you registered another app in Azure AD, this situation may cause 403 error. Please check if you add the right permission of your function app in "API permissions" tab of the newly registered app.